# How do I submit data to a web form in python?

Tags: python, automation, python-3.x, bots, webforms

I'm trying to automate the process of creating an account for something, lets call it X, but I cant figure out what to do.

I saw this code somewhere,

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser

data = urllib.urlencode({'q': 'Python'})
url = 'http://duckduckgo.com/html/'
full_url = url + '?' + data
response = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.read())

webbrowser.open("results.html")
```

But I cant figure out how to modify it for my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend utilizing Selenium+Webdriver for this, since your question appears UI and browser-based. You can install Selenium via 'pip install selenium' in most cases. Here are a couple of good references to get started.
- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
Also, if this process needs to drive the browser headlessly, look into including PhantomJS (via GhostDriver), which can be downloaded from the phantomjs.org website.